# Keeping finished jobs' pods (not cronjobs)

Tags: kubernetes

Kubernetes CronJobs allow to specify following:

```yaml
successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3 
failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
```

However this is not the case for Kubernetes Jobs – these fields are undefined and the pods are immediately deleted after completion.

Is there a way to keep the jobs' pods after completion for inspection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to keep alive is let him doing something.
When your job run and the work is finished it exits with code 0, when an error occours it exits with a different code.

If you need to access your container after the job is finished let him do someting like "sleep infinity".....

In your podTemplate of your job.yaml

```
    command:
    - sh
    - -c
    - |
      myjobcommand
      sleep 999999
```

Update

To log terminated pods use the -p switch

```
kubectl logs podname -p -n mynamespace
```

it should work till 1 hour (default settings) after the pod terminated

Comment: And what about if the container crashes? It seems also to be immediately removed.

Comment: i posted an updated. However if this is important to you, i would implement container logging, with fluentd or logstash for example. I use fluentd. Not so much hard to set up